# An intrinsic to shift left/right based on a mask

Tags: c, x86, intrinsics, avx2, avx512

I'm trying to combine a left and right shift and I was wondering if there's a built-in intrinsic for it that I don't know about.

```
uint32_t x = whatever;

if(value < 0) {
    x <<= value;
} else {
    x >>= value;
}

//The way I would do it
_a = _mm256_sllv_epi32(x, shiftValues);
_b = _mm256_srlv_epi32(x, shiftValues);
_value = some gather / blend function to merge _a and _b
```

I'm limiting my intrinsic list to mm256 since that's all my processor can support but if there's an mm512 intrinsic for this problem I'll still keep it in note. Thanks

I have looked through the [intel intrinsics list](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#cats=Shift&text=_mm256&ig_expand=6574) for something of the sorts but the naming scheme isn't the most "aha! that's a thing" at least when I read "sllv".

Comment: Did you try to simply apply the top optimization level? Look at the resulting machine code.

Comment: @thebusybee I had figured the compiler wouldn't know what to do with intrinsics or at least I would have to baby it, and plus I dont want to throw a high level request at the cpu and hope for the best. Havent looked at the compiler output but if it didn't come up with a function because it didn't pick up what I was trying to do but there is a function for it, then I have missed out on an intrinsic I didnt know existed

Comment: Yeah, `sllv` + `srlv`, and `_mm256_blendv_ps` would do it (with some `_mm256_castps_si256` and the reverse to keep the compiler happy).  That will use the sign bit of the shift count as the blend control.  For variable-blend on integers, there's only one for byte elements, which would take an extra instruction (like `vpsrad` by 31, or `vpcmpgtd` against zero) to get the top bit of all 4 bytes set, so you might as well just use an FP blend for 32-bit elements, even if that has a cycle of extra latency.

Comment: Except SIMD shifts will saturate the shift count, not mask, so the `x <<= value` one probably needs to be `x <<= -value`.  Oh, if `value` is in the -31 .. +31 range, the high bits of every byte will already match, so you can use `_mm256_blendv_epi8`.

Comment: What @thebusybee was suggesting was trying something with intrinsics, compiling it with clang on https://godbolt.org/, and *if* you got lucky and it compiled to fewer instructions than you'd used intrinsics, you could translate its asm back to more efficient intrinsics.  Or at least look up the intrinsics for the instructions it used and put those in your mental toolbox, while looking for ones of similar names.  If it didn't compile efficiently, then oh well, didn't hurt to try.  Of course you don't want to just blindly hope for the best, look at the compiler's asm when micro-optimizing.

Comment: `vpsrlvw`, `vpsrlvd` and `vpsrlvq` will produce a zero result, if the corresponding (unsigned) shift amount is larger than 16/32/64 -- same is true for left shifts, of course. Since negative integers interpreted as unsigned integers are certainly bigger, you can simply bit-or the shift-results `(x << value) | (x >> -value)`. This does not work, if you want arithmetic shifts, though.